# NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

Eu estava fazendo testes, até que recebi o seguinte erro:

> Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object

Pesquisando descobri que é o famoso `NullReferenceException`, então fui obrigado a fazer diversas verificações no código, como eu mostro a seguir, mas acredito que fazer todas essas verificações não seja bom em relação a tempo de execução, estou certo? Se eu estiver existe uma outra maneira de resolver isso ou de fazer essas verificações de uma maneira mais rápida?

```
var UrlApi2 = "api/EstoqueExterno/create";

if (ambienteViewModel.EstExt_endereco == null)
   ambienteModel2.EstExt_endereco = "";

else
   ambienteModel2.EstExt_endereco = ambienteViewModel.EstExt_endereco.ToUpper();

   ambienteModel2.EstTp_Codigo = ambienteViewModel.EstTp_Codigo;


if (ambienteViewModel.EstExt_senha == null)
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_senha = "";

else
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_senha = ambienteViewModel.EstExt_senha.ToUpper();

if (ambienteViewModel.EstExt_usuario == null)
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_usuario = "";

else
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_usuario = ambienteViewModel.EstExt_usuario.ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o operador de coalescência nula `??` que  retorna operando esquerdo se o operando não for nulo e caso contrário ele retornará o operando direito.

Usando sua última condição como exemplo:

```cs
if (ambienteViewModel.EstExt_usuario == null)
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_usuario = "";

else
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_usuario = ambienteViewModel.EstExt_usuario.ToUpper();
```

que pode ser reescrita como:

```
ambienteModel2.EstExt_usuario = (ambienteViewModel.EstExt_usuario ?? "").ToUpper();
```

Comment: Legal, me poupou algumas linhas de código kk, obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Você pode substituir esse código:

```
if (ambienteViewModel.EstExt_senha == null)
    ambienteModel2.EstExt_senha = "";
```

Por esse:

```
ambienteModel2?.EstExt_senha ?? "";
```

Adicionando o `?` antes do `.` é verificado se `ambienteModel2` é nulo, caso NÃO seja, ele chama o método `EstExt_senha`, caso seja nulo não é executado o `EstExt_senha`. Já o `??` verifica se existe algum valor em `EstExt_senha`, caso o valor seja nulo (conforme seu exemplo), atribui `" "` a variável.

Comment: Gostei desse código, tem uma verificação  a mais.

Comment: mas o que seria `null` era a propriedade _EstExt_senha_ de _ambienteViewModel_, poderia fazer era: `ambienteModel2.EstExt_senha = ambienteViewModel.EstExt_senha?.ToUpper();` mas ficaria a `null` em caso de `null` e não `""`.

Comment: Sim, acredito que a verificação do `ambienteModel2?` não seja necessária, mas gostei da resposta, irei aceitar a do Augusto pois achei mais completa pro meu problema, mas agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Valeu pelas considerações, agradeço!